Module fortran: -frecord-marker=8 don't recognize
The Fortran module does not recognize frecord-marker=8
Good morning.
I need to use this Fortran subroutine in Python (via ctypes) to read a binary file:
reader.f95:

subroutine readdata() bind(c, name='readdata')
    use iso_c_binding
    .....


write(*,'(/,A)')'Reading marco file...'
    !OPEN LINK FILE
    IR4 = 12

OPEN(UNIT=IR4,FILE="...",STATUS='OLD',FORM='UNFORMATTED',IOSTAT=IERR)
    IF (IERR/=0)STOP 'FAILED TO OPEN LINK FILE - CHECK!'

    READ(IR4) ROOL
    WRITE(*,*) "ROOL: ", ROOL

    ....

    CLOSE(IR4)

end subroutine readdata

When I launch the command via the Linux terminal (with -frecord-marker=8):
gfortran -shared -frecord-marker=8 -o reader.so reader.f95

the module reader.so is created correctly.
But when I try to execute this Python script:
import ctypes as ct

directory = '.../reader.so'

fortlib = ct.CDLL(directory)  

fortlib.readdata.argtypes = []

fortlib.readdata()

it gives me this error as if it does not recognize the command -frecord-marker=8 (it reads it as -frecord-marker=4):
Reading marco file...
ROOL:
At line 18 of file reader.f95 (unit = 12, file = 'FLTGEO.LIX')
Fortran runtime error: I/O past end of record on unformatted file
I am using the following version of gfortran:
GNU Fortran (GCC) 13.2.1 20230801
Any solutions?


From the error message, how do you conclude that "it does not recognize the command -frecord-marker=8"? and 2) How has the file been created?


I concur with what PierU wrote. What is the reason for which you want to use an 8-byte record marker in the first place? Tobe sure, check that you are opening the right file. I would recommend to also use action="read" and even explicit access="sequential" evenif it does not change anything here. What is ROOL? How big is it? Is there anything else in the file besides ROOL? How much is there? How many bytes does the full file have?

I have to use -frecord-marker=8 because some files I need to read have this record length. Rool is a variable that reads the first three characters of the file (CHARACTER*3 ROOL). I tried using action="read" and access="sequential" but it gives me the same error. Without the module but using the subroutine for another Fortran program, everything works

If on linux, could you give the output of the two following commands: od -t u4 FLTGEO.LIX | head 1 and od -t c FLTGEO.LIX | head 1 ? Also, what should contain ROO if read correctly ?

od -t c FLTGEO.LIX | head -1
0000000 003  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0   F   L   T 003  \0  \0  \0  \0
od -t u4 FLTGEO.LIX | head -1
0000000          3          0   55856198          0

Indeed your file has apparently 8 bytes record markers. That it's difficult to be sure where the problem comes from. A workaround may be to open the file in stream access mode and decoding the record markers by yourself.

OK, I misread the original error message (eof vs eor). Indeed, decoding the records yourself could be a solution. I think the -frecord-marker= is probably used for the created executable, not for a single object or a library. It probably just modifies some parameter for the runtime library at the program start or something similar.

See RTFM: 6.3 Non-Fortran Main Program https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gfortran/Non-Fortran-Main-Program.html
